# How can I run two instances of tomcat 7.0 per eclipse different ports?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

Project1: http1.1=8080 ajp1.3=8009; Project2: http1.1=8085 ajp1.3=8010. When I run Project2 in eclipseit starts up ok.  However, when I startup the second in eclipse it says tomcat has a problem....this is all after cleaning both projects and a reboot.

Comment: To run multiple tomcat servers, the AJP port, tomcat admin port and HTTP port need to be modified. eclipse Juno supports editing them. Not sure what is causing it to be read-only. Perhaps a issue with eclipse workspace. Try cleaning or recreating the workspace

Comment: Even after rebuilding and cleaning there seems to issues with either running it on windows or it's not possible or I have bad port choices.  Project1: http1.1=8080 ajp1.3=8009; Project2: http1.1=8085 ajp1.3=8010. When I run Project2 in eclipseit starts up ok..the second in eclipse it says tomcat has a problem....this is all after cleaning both projects and a reboot.

Comment: what is the exact error? would you provide the message? log, stack, something!

Comment: @user2511414 This is what I get when I start up project 2 after project 1 is already running. http://bit.ly/126pUjg

Comment: @JaJ  so it says the port you are trying to listen is already in use! maybe you started the 2nd. instance outside the eclipse environment, just try to change the port and try, also sometimes eclipse says the tomcat is shutdown, but you need to kill is from task manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the screenshot, eclipse complains that "tomcat admin port" 8005 is already in use. Please change this under Ports ( in addition to changing http 1.1 and ajp1.3). I think you had mentioned that the port appears to be readonly. If that is the case, the port could be directly modified in the server.xml located in your workspace.

File location:   <>\Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config\server.xml
Locate the following line in server.xml and modify it. Refresh your eclipse and it should reflect in the UI.

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Comment: DOH! Yep, that was it.  Admin port. SUCCESS! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

For 2nd instance change the server port to some other port  like 8010[image]10 ...it will work

Answer (score 1):

You need to change all the three port numbers as in the pic

[image]